# center a block in which it is applied display inline-block

Tags: css

I have a div which contains an img now I would center it but if I try `margin: 0 auto` it doesn't work.

```
<div style="display: inline-block">

   <img src=""/>

</div>
```

how can I center the entire div including also the img?

Comment: If the DIV didn't have any dynamic width. Then define width to your DIV because margin:0 auto; only works on fixed width

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `text-align: center` to the container of the div:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
       <img src="..."/>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vtEW5/)**

Comment: Ok it worked perfectly but I don't understand why...I mean in the div I don't have any text only img...this property it is used only for text?

Comment: Well, this property specifies how the **inline content** of a block is aligned. So it works for text and other inlined elements. This is the case in your example because the contained div is `inline-block`.

Answer (score 3):

just giving `text-align: center` to the  parent of your inline-block div

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzgeE/)

Maybe you already know, but note that this won't work everywhere because IE<8 won't apply `display: inline-block` to your `<div>` element (and no hack can help you): from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

> IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline.

So I suggest to use another element (like a simple inline `<span>`) or, if you use HTML5, pick one of new available elements: since they're not recognized on older IE browser you can style them as inline blocks without problem. In this scenario a `<figure>` element could be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to CENTER the image inside your INLINE-BLOCK div then you need to assign following styling to your img tag

```
 position:relative;  
 left: 50%;    
 margin-left: -57px; /*Negative half of the width of the image */
```

Here is demo. http://jsfiddle.net/5eU3Y/

BUT if you want to CENTER div itself then you need to assign container text-align: center; property. Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/5eU3Y/1/

But if you want to CENTER ONLY this inline-div block then you must know its width.
Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/5eU3Y/2/